# Import all headers from path and the name of headers didn't know before

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, import, header

How can I import all header files from a path where the name of the headers is unknown beforehand?

I would like to `#import` header files with unknown name automatically. If it's possible, how can I do that? please tell me step by step because I have spent time for 4-5 days for solve this problem, but I can't. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Will you please elaborate quite more what do you want to know.

Normally, what we do we make a file and at that file we do import and later just use that single file to include so that no multiple files get include or can say trying to make distance with cross reference and also, what you can do, include that single file in your project pch file.

Hope, it'll what you need. :)

Comment: I mean my project is about Augmented Reality. The 3D model file normally is .obj but for using, I must convert it into .h file. In .h file, there are 3 variables that I must use for rendering 3D and all of .h file can add by user. So why all of .h file are did't know the name of header before. That is the problem that I have noway to know what name of header which has to type in plist. Is it possible to auto import from directory?